# look up and display only a certain range of rows in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am wondering how do I display a certain range of rows based on a fixed value:

```
y<-c(1,59,60,65,85,86,1550,97)
z<-c(1:8)
test<-cbind(y,z)
test

y z
[1,]    1 1
[2,]   59 2
[3,]   60 3
[4,]   65 4
[5,]   85 5
[6,]   86 6
[7,] 1550 7
[8,]   97 8
```

So say, it just so happens that I need to see only +/-2 rows from 85, is there a way I can extract  from the table? Ideally, I would like to have something like this:

[image]

Thanks a lot for helping.

**Updated version with new function written by Peter :**

```
#required libiaries

library(quantmod)
library(pedquant)

# download option chain from yahoo finance, using an example of ticker "BABA" & exp= "2023-06-23"
ticker<-c("BABA")
options<-getOptionChain(ticker,Exp="2023-06-23")

# seperate call/put options and display only Strike, Last Price, Volume
call_option<-options$calls[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]
put_option<-options$puts[,c("Strike","Last","Vol")]

#getting the updated stock price to filter at-the-money level 

ticker_price<-md_stock(ticker,type="real")
price<-ticker_price$close

view_window <- function(dfr, var, x, pm){
  
  idx <- which(abs(test[, var]-x) == min(abs(test[, var] - x)))
  
  return(dfr[(idx - pm) : (idx + pm), ])
  
}

view_window(dfr=call_option,
            var=call_option$Strike,
            x=price,pm=3)

Error in test[, var] : subscript out of bounds
```

In this example, data frame [dfr] is call_option, var is call_option$Strike, x is the traded price, however, an error msg of "Error in test[, var] : subscript out of bounds" is shown, pretty sure something is wrong with the format of my data frame n the function should have been working perfectly. Any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a function like this:

```r
# Where
# dfr is your data frame
# var is the quoted variable name you want to use 
# x is the value of the variable you want to centre your subset on, and 
# pm is the plus and minus range of the subset

view_window <- function(dfr, var, x, pm){

  idx <- which(abs(test[, var]-x) == min(abs(test[, var] - x)))
  
  return(dfr[(idx - pm) : (idx + pm), ])
  
}

view_window(dfr = test,
            var = "y",
            x = 85,
            pm = 2)
#>         y z
#> [1,]   60 3
#> [2,]   65 4
#> [3,]   85 5
#> [4,]   86 6
#> [5,] 1550 7
```

Limits of the function:
if x within the plus or minus index of the first or last value in the subject vector the function will fail.
I've not tested the effect if there are multiple values in the subject column which are equal to x.

<sup>Created on 2023-06-21 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks a lot, may I also ask, if end up x=85.4 but not 85, here instead of rounding, is there a way I could still locate 85.4 to the closest integer in y column? Cheers

Comment: Do you mean x in the function is 85.4  or there is a value of 85.4 in the subject column. By the way I should have added a few caveats like it will probably fail if the selected value is close to the top or bottom of the table and the range takes you outside of the table.

Comment: I meant x in the function is 85.4. thank u so much , cheers

Comment: This can get rather tricky as it depends on the values in the subject variable. You could modify the function to replace `x` with `ceiling(x)` which will force indexing on the integer greater than x; this assumes that there will be a matching integer in your subject variable.

Comment: thanks so much, what I have on my mind is that, values in y column are fixed, and value for x will be constantly changing, what I wanna do is to match x to the closest y value and display plus/minus range, so ur function nicely covers it all. Thanks a lot.

Comment: See updated function with a more robust method of determining the index of the closest match in the subject column.

Comment: thanks a lot, I was just thinking how to use either ceiling or floor function to modify , now ur updated function is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: tested the function and it works very well, however, seeing an subscript out of bounds issue, mind taking a look? Thanks.

Comment: Try `var = "Strike"` instead of `var = call_option$Strike`.

Comment: Bingo, there we go :) it works!